# The Masai tribe in Africa drink blood of a living cow. Is this Ever Min haChai? And what about cow's milk?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws

Is piercing into a live cow and extracting the blood for drinking considered ever min hachai for non Jews?   This is what the Masai tribe in Africa do. It allows them to get continuous nutrition without killing the cow. I am looking for real examples of ever min hachai. I know two others. Vendyl Jones, the Noachide leader , told of what they would do on his Ranch in Texas. When they castrated the bulls ( I don't know why) they would make a special dish from what they cut off.   And then on a tour of a Monkey Park in South Africa, the guide told of an exotic delicacy in some Asian Culture of eating monkey brains straight from a live animal. I can't imagine how.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48408/759

Comment: re testicles / lamb fries / rock mountain oysters see here [judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109496](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109496/what-counts-as-an-eiver-min-hachai-to-be-forbidden/109513#109513)